# Removing two words together (Phrase) from Text in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, text-mining

I am trying to remove words from the 20K comments. Words are stored in dataframe and its around more than 2000. Comments in different dataframe and its around 20K.

Below is the example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.Dataframe()   
data = ['Hull Damage happened and its insured by maritime hull insurance company','Non Cash Entry and claims are blocked']  

stopwords = ['Hull insurance', 'Non Cash Entry']
```

Expected Output:

```
output = ['Hull Damage happened and its insured by maritime company','and claims are blocked']
```

Comment: Could you please give some more examples and expected output, thank you

Comment: Text1: Hull Damage happened and await further for the process  Text2: Hit on vessel and further action needed.  I want my output as Hull Damage Happened and for the process... Hit on Vessel and needed. I will give Await further and Further action phrases to remove from the text

Comment: I still don't get it man please  put it onto your question and format the code because it is not understandable in the comments

Comment: I have added the example in the comment , please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pd.series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) which accepts regex also. see below example.

```
import pandas as pd

data = ['Hull Damage happened and its insured by maritime hull insurance company','Non Cash Entry and claims are blocked']
replace_data = ['hull insurance', 'Non Cash Entry']    #strings which needs to be replaced

df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': data})    #data added in dataframe as column1

pattern = '|'.join(replace_data)    #created a pattern from replace_data strings

df['column1'] = df['column1'].str.replace(pattern, '')    #replaced the pattern string with null

print(df['column1'])
```